# Canonical functions in set theory and their applications

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Given regular cardinal $\kappa>\omega,$ we can define the canonical functions $f_\alpha: \kappa\to \kappa,$ for $\alpha<\kappa^+.$

Some of their properties are presented in Chapter 22 of the book **"Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory"** by Péter Komjáth and Vilmos Totik.

**(A)** I am looking for more references and additional properties of these functions.

**(B)** I also want to know what are the main applications of these functions, and how they can be used in proving theorems (in particular $ZFC$ results).

Comment: Canonical functions can also be found in Jech Ch. 24 Lem 24.5.

Comment: Also, the handbook of set theory page 99 refers to canonical functions as well along with other places.

Answer (score 5):

In belated partial response to (A), canonical functions are certainly already defined in the Jech-Shelah paper: [A note on canonical functions](http://www.math.psu.edu/jech/preprints/canon.pdf), where reference is made to the work F. Galvin and A. Hajnal, *Inequalities for cardinal powers*, Annals of Math. 101 (1975), 491-498. The name "canonical" appears to derive from the property that if they exist, they are unique up to equivalence modulo a club. Below $\aleph_2$, they always exist; at or above, they may or may not.